# How to copy a range within a row from one excel sheet to another based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a row from one excel sheet (JOBS MASTER SHEET) into another (BBG SPECIALIST REPORTS) based on a certain cell value(J). So if J ="1" then I copy that entire row to "BBG SPECIALIST REPORTS"
This is the code I have used. Although I don't want to copy the entire row just cells from A to R. Can you help me change this code accordingly.

```
Sub PPS()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets("JOBS MASTER SHEET").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim x As Long
    x = 3
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Sheets("JOBS MASTER SHEET").Range("J3:J" & LastRow)
        If rng = "1" Then
            rng.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("BBG SPECIALIST REPORTS").Cells(x, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `rng.EntireRow.Columns("A:R").Copy` instead `rng.EntireRow.Copy`

Answer (score 0):

### Copy (Filter) Rows Containing Criteria Using Arrays

- This solution also allows the criteria column not to be contained in the destination (source).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PPS()
    
    Const sName As String = "JOBS MASTER SHEET"
    Const sFirst As String = "J3"
    Const sCols As String = "A:R"
    Const dName As String = "BBG SPECIALIST REPORTS"
    Const dFirst As String = "A3"
    Const Criteria As Variant = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim scrg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    With sws.Range(sFirst)
        Dim slCell As Range
        Set slCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If slCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        rCount = slCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set scrg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    Dim scData As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim scData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): scData(1, 1) = scrg.Value
    Else
        scData = scrg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = scrg.EntireRow.Columns(sCols)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(sData, 2)
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If scData(r, 1) = Criteria Then
            n = n + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                sData(n, c) = sData(r, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next r
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dFirst).Resize(n, cCount)
    drg.Value = sData
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - n + 1).Offset(n).ClearContents

End Sub
```